# {-truncated-} in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving a problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem). I actually solved it, but it worked only on 4 tests. When I unlocked the testcase my program couldn't pass, I have seen this in input:

```
100
997 981 957 933 930 927 926 920 916 896 887 874 863 863 858 847 815 809 803 794 789 785 783 778 764 755 751 740 737 730 691 677 652 650 587 585 583 568 546 541 540 538 531 527 506 493 457 435 430 427 422 422 414 404 400 394 387 384 374 371 369 369 368 365 363 337 336 328 325 316 314 306 282 277 230 227 212 199 179 173 171 168 136 125 124 95 92 88 85 70 68 61 60 59 44 43 28 23 13 12
200
12 20 30 32 35 37 63 72 83 85 96 98 98 118 122 125 129 132 140 144 150 164 184 191 194 198 200 220 228 229 229 236 238 246 259 271 276 281 283 287 300 302 306 307 312 318 321 325 341 341 341 344 349 351 354 356 366 369 370 379 380 380 396 405 408 417 423 429 433 435 438 441 442 444 445 445 452 453 465 466 467 468 469 471 475 482 489 491 492 493 498 500 501 504 506 508 523 529 530 539 543 551 552 556 568 569 571 587 591 601 602 606 607 612 614 619 620 623 625 625 627 638 645 653 661 662 669 670 676 684 689 690 709 709 710 716 724 726 730 731 733 737 744 744 747 757 764 765 765 772 773 774 777 787 794 796 797 802 805 811 814 {-truncated-}
```

And it says the output should be:

```
97
96
94
94
94
94
89
87
87
86
83
83
83
83
83
81
81
81
80
80{-truncated-}
```

However my output is everything besides this {-truncated-}. So, I'm confused about what this "truncated" means. Is it mistake in a test or I really should handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {-truncated-}

has nothing to do with the output. Its just Hackerranks way of saying (there are more values for the output than we want to show in this window)

Comment: So, it's a bug in my program?

Comment: Yes. If you hit the download button near the box that has truncated in it a new window will open with the full output and you can see where your output doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to hackerrank and it confuzed me a bit